# Integration Derivation physical intuition?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, control-theory

I know mathematically the procedure of computing**derivative** and **integral** but I don't perceive the*concept* being that, I mean, I want to know**physically what's a derivative** because it's really weird how *integrator getting 0 input, yields a constant output* , **physically what's a derivative and integrator?**

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out these two articles:

https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-calculus-analogy-integrals-as-multiplication/

https://betterexplained.com/articles/calculus-building-intuition-for-the-derivative/

Succinctly, integrals are a form of better multiplication over changing variables and derivatives are better division over changing variables.

Comment: It would be good to explain the most important points of those articles here in your answer.

Comment: It's really good answer.جزاک اللہ